macOS gives an Error when using char16_t / std::u16string
I tried to use  char16_t /  u16string on MacOS, but I get an error:
std::u16string aaa = u"-d";
const char16_t* cc = u"abcd";

Error:  "use of undeclared identifier 'u' gcc [ln...]"  

Does anyone know why that is?
I am on mac Sonoma, VSCode, C++ g++.

Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us, and copy-paste the full and complete build-log of that example into your question. Also please tell us what compiler you're using, what version of it, and the flags and options you use.


I am on mac Sonoma, VSCode, C++ g++.

my main question is how are you compiling this? what commands are you running.  i can compile this using the following commands
main.cpp
#include<string>

int main() {
  std::u16string aaa = u"-d";
  const char16_t* cc = u"abcd";
}

command
g++ --std=c++20 main.cpp

im fairly postive that you are forgetting to set the standard version when you are building with --std=c++20 so you will be using a older standard.

His compiler has to be very old, though. I had the same idea, compiled with just g++ Test.cpp, and it worked just fine. Turns out, these literals as well as std::u16string are actually C++ 11... so for his compiler to default to something even older...

@ChristianStieber My guess is that the OP is using the default alias for GCC, which points to Clang. And for some reason Clang defaults to the C++98 standard.

@Someprogrammerdude oh... ok. While 98>11, that sounds like a reason. Even more so since Apple loves clang.
